# Why is 'Did anybody said something?' grammatically incorrect?

Tags: grammar

"Did anybody said something?" is an incorrect sentence grammatically, but I don't get why.

This might be an excessively silly question, but I am new to the English Language.

Comment: *Did anybody **say** something?* is perfectly grammatical (but not a common question to ask). Your version is syntactically invalid because you've already inflected ***did*** for tense, so the associated main verb should be an *unmarked infinitive*.

Comment: Per the first comment on the original, [You cannot have two finite forms in the same verbal unit.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/160094/did-you-just-present-or-past-tense#comment333899_160094)

Comment: if im not mistaken, you can keep the 'said' by saying "has anybody said something?"

Comment: exactly @AlanCarmack

Answer (score 2):

When adding a `does/doesn't/did/didn't` to a sentence, the main verb returns to it's base form (V1 instead of V2). That's why you say:

> She didn't **like** me

And not

> She didn't **liked** me

And that's why you ask:

> Did he **go** to the gym?

And not

> Did he **went** to the gym?

Comment: and all these things are happening in past

Comment: Oh, you're right. I have given wrong examples. Let me fix that

Comment: V1 and V2 have zero meaning to me and probably for most people, in this context .

Comment: @AlanCarmack Can you explain why they have zero meaning?

Comment: @YotamSalmon It's zero meaning because you're showing a notation you only know because of what you were taught. You should add parentheses to explain away the notation you used.